# simplexml_load_file() error

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm relatively new with PHP and more so with XML.

I have a script working perfectly on my localhost, but when I try and put it on my Server, I get this message:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file()
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   http://api.wefeelfine.org:8080/ShowFeelings?display=xml&feeling=happy&returnfields=imageid,feeling,sentence,posttime,postdate,posturl,gender,country,state,city,lat,lon&limit=0&extraimages=20:1:
>
> parser error : Document is empty in
>   /home2/alsweet/public_html/notalone.php
>   on line 21

The line of code which is not working is this:

```
// get api feed
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.wefeelfine.org:8080/ShowFeelings?display=xml&feeling=' . $feeling . '&returnfields=imageid,feeling,sentence,posttime,postdate,posturl,gender,country,state,city,lat,lon&limit=0&extraimages=20');
```

Have I made a mistake? 
Should I be speaking to my hosting provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was infact a problem with my hosting,

it turns out it was becuase i was trying to call out to another server on port 8080 which was not open outbound in the firewall. so they opened it and it works fine.

thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using the url you have in your xml loader I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<feelings>
</feelings>
```

So it should be parsing fine.  Check with your hosting provider to make sure simplexml_load_file is supported.

Comment: I don't think that's in the actual URL he's using its just the error output. See that his source code doesn't have the ":1"

Comment: @KThompson You're right, I didn't scroll over to see that.  When using his url though, I get an empty set.

Comment: I actually got multiple elements returned using "feeling=happy". simplexml appears to work because the error only indicates an error in the URL not that the function doesn exists or something like that

Comment: Okay should be supported by your hosting then. Any idea what version of PHP is on your server?

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.13 according to the phpinfo();

Comment: Yeah I think it should be working fine.  As a last ditch effort you can always get the xml using curl and convert it using SimpleXMLElement or simplexml_load_string.

Answer (score 0):

Try isolating that line and see if that it indeed where the problem is coming from. Run this code in its own file and see if that works.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.wefeelfine.org:8080/ShowFeelings?display=xml&feeling=happy&returnfields=imageid,feeling,sentence,posttime,postdate,posturl,gender,country,state,city,lat,lon&limit=0&extraimages=20');

print_r($xml);

?>
```

Comment: This is one nice way to figure things out. :)
But this should rather be a comment :P ;)